# Shorcut for `Run Line(s)` in Octave / Matlab

Tags: octave

In RStudio it is `Ctrl+Enter`, while in PyCharm it is `Ctrl+backslash`, but I can't find a similar shortcut for Octave (not so interested in Matlab). There has to be a way to run a single line of code on the editor without running the entire document. I know there is a method to run chunks of code, but this doesn't seem practical, either.

Comment: Matlab has "cells" in the editor, which are blocks of code delimited by special comments that can be run via hotkey.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think this is what I was trying to convey with the word "chunks", which I borrowed from Markdown. But isn't there something better than copying and pasting a line of code from the Editor to the Console?

Comment: There's also a hotkey for "run highlighted code", which would require you to select the line first.  This one basically does copy/paste into the Command window.

Comment: @BenVoigt That would work... I now have to find the equivalent in Octave...

Comment: I found it: Highlight the line and press `F9` or go to the menu, and under "Run" click on "Run selection."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to select the code that you want to run first. The actual shortcut to then execute the selection is configurable (Edit > Preferences...) but defaults to F9.

Or you can right click on the editor which shows you the options and shortcut:

[image]

Comment: So there is no way still to run the line without highlighting?

It feels quite cumbersome to move the hand to the mouse, highlight, and then back to keyboard and press F9. Even shift-left/up is messy as you have to leave a blank line between each line of code to prevent highlighting half the code from the line above.